# How can I bypass GoDaddy Inode Limit (fixed to 250000 files) to store a lot of image?

Tags: php, image, php-ziparchive, inode

I've a lot of jpg images:
About 30000 folder containing 5 images each --> Total amount it's about 150000 images and I want to reduce the inode number (file count on the server) because it's placed into my hosting server.
So, now it's ok but if in future I will have more than 250000 files what can I do without add a secondary hosting plan?

Comment: What "image URL" are you trying to get, exactly?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to use the images for example into an HTML image tag!

Comment: So then are you asking how to extract them from the archive file, so you can have a PHP page that returns the image data?  What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: This approach is generally bad. You should avoid getting image from compressed file (zip) each request to page. It will be terribly slow.
Why inode number on the server is so important to you?

Comment: Yes, I want to extract the image and useit into the html but theese images have to be deleted when page is closed!

Comment: @DevilaN, my godaddy hosting have the inode limit to 250000 and now it's ok but if in the future I'll have more than 250000 images it will be a trouble

Comment: If it is only a matter of file numbers, than better way would be serving those files from database.

Comment: Yes, I can save it into MySQL but I can have only ten DB no more than 1GB each

Comment: You should change your question to sth like: "How can I bypass godaddy's limits" then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This limitation is of Shared hosting of Godaddy.

You can Purchase VPS / Dedicated server to user more number of files for your website. Or you can Purchase Cloud space from Amozone and Push all images to Amazone server and give links to your active DB.